# Solving a second order ODE substituting $y'=v$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was given this problem

$$
    y'y'' = 1
$$

and told to solve it using the method in which

$y' = v$ and $y'' = v \frac{dv}{dy}$.

I had previously solved it using the method in which you substitute

$v = y'$ and $v' = y''$ getting
$$y=\frac{1}{3}(2x + c_1)^\frac{3}{2} + c_2$$

which was correct, but I can't get the same answer using the method I first mentioned. Here is my work:

$$
    y'y''=1 
$$
$$
    v^2\frac{dv}{dy}=1
$$
$$
    \frac{v^3}{3} = y + c_1
$$
$$
    \frac{dy}{dx} = (y+c_1)^\frac{1}{3}
$$
$$
    x = \frac{3}{2}(y+c_1)^\frac{2}{3} + c_2
$$

However this in terms of y is not the same as the answer I got earlier. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

The second question is:

$$y''+y=0$$

I've also been told to solve this using the same method. The only way I've ever solved the before is inspection. Knowing that $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ fit and putting them into $$y = c_1y_1(x) + c_2y_2(x)$$ which is $$y=c_1\sin(x) + c_2\cos(x)$$.

However trying to solve it the way I've indicated I get:

$$v\frac{dv}{dy}=-y$$
$$vdv = -ydy$$
$$v = \sqrt{c_1-y^2}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{c_1-y^2}$$
$$x = \int{\frac{dy}{\sqrt{c_1-y^2}}}$$
$$x = \arctan(\frac{y}{\sqrt{c_1-y^2}}) + c_2$$

And then I'm just lost

Comment: My textbook was unclear so I referenced this page:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Second-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html

Which said let $v=y'$

Comment: I updated my post to show my work. Could you take a look and see where I went wrong?

Comment: Thank you! This fixes it. However, I have a followup question that I would like to post if you could wait for me to edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem, was the missing factor 3 in the 2nd last equation.

The second problem is then
\begin{align}
\tan(x+c) &= \frac{y}{\sqrt{d-y^2}} \Rightarrow \\
(\tan(x+c))^2 &= \frac{y^2}{d-y^2} \iff \\
(\tan(x+c))^2 (d-y^2) &= y^2 \iff \\
d (\tan(x+c))^2  &= (1+(\tan(x+c))^2) y^2
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
y &= \pm \frac{\sqrt{d} \tan(x+c)}{\sqrt{1+(\tan(x+c))^2}} \\
  &= \pm \frac{\sqrt{d} \tan(x+c)}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos(x+c))^2}}} \\
  &= \pm \sqrt{d} \sin(x+c) \\
  &= \pm \sqrt{d} \left[\sin(c) \cos(x) + \cos(c) \sin(x) \right]
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes a lot of sense.